# New line character in excel when printing from vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, excel, newline, stringbuilder

I am trying to print a value to a cell that contains a line seperator like <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> or `Char(10)`. Everything so far just prints my text so that it prints the values I want to wrap in the excel are in different cells

In my `vb.net` code I keep building a string as I loop through reports and I have tried `vbcrlf`, `vblf` etc to try and mimic a <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> entry in excel using something similar to the below

```
_string = _string & vbcrlf & report.name &" " & _pctstatus &"%"
```

and then I paste this string into A1 using

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject(_string.ToString, False)
aRange.Select()
aWorkSheet.Paste()
```

In the picture you can see I keep getting the values in A3 but I really want the result in A1

[image: Excel output]

I can get around this by structuring my text as formula so that `Char(10)` is in the cell formula but I would prefer just enter a string value and have no formulae. I also have to do this as I am constrained by the number of free cells in the excel report since I am adding this an excel sheet heavily populated already

Comment: Not familiar with .net but I don't think the problem is in the string structure. Either vbLF or VBcrlf should work as the separator.  If aRange is set to A1, can you do something, in .net, like aRange.value = string ?  Instead of going through the select/clipboard/copy/paste sequence?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld `aRange.Value = _string.ToString` will work. This is only a snippet of a larger string that gets pasted into a template workbook. I would rather avoid having to monitor which cells I will need to override manually. But, like you say, I suspect I may be forced into this option given the string structure

Answer (score 1):

So is any special need to use clipboard?
If not try this:

```
aRange.Value = _string.ToString
```

Comment: `aRange.Value = _string.ToString` will work. This is only a snippet of a larger string that gets pasted into a template workbook. I would rather avoid having to monitor which cells I will need to override manually since this could happen any number of times during the process.

Answer (score 1):

Is the format of the cell set to allow multiple lines (Wrap Text)?

Comment: yes the problem is that the values get put in the cell below rather than wrapping the text in the desired cell

Answer (score 0):

Just use `vbLf` instead of `vbCrLf`.

Comment: Strange: I just tried it in Excel, from VBA, and it gives the appropriate result. Can't you just write to the range, instead of going through teh clipboard ? Edit: just like @Ron Rosenfeld suggested

Comment: ya just double checked hmmmm. I guessed since you can paste wrapped text in `VBA` there should be some likeness in `vb.net`. I can do as @Ron Rosenfeld but I will have to then monitor what cells I'm entering these values in and then override the values at the end of the method. Some days this could mean overwriting hundreds of cells. Bit messy and hoping for a more elegant solution. Thanks